# Data Flow task showing error when the oledb connection string is parameterized in an SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have an `ssis package` with a simple dataflow task with package level connection manager. When I parameterized the `connection string`, the dataflow task showing the error. I have given the parameter value as copied from the connection string property of the corresponding connection manager.  I have set the `protectionlevel` property to **encryptsensitivewithpassword**.

Should i change any value of the parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

set DelayValidation to True in the properties window for the data flow task

Answer (score 0):

With out error we can't predict the solution for your issue , but in most of the cases it's because of **Delay Validation** set it to **TRUE**.

You can refer the below link for the more details about the `delay validation` in `SSIS`.

[http://www.dbafire.com/2015/10/07/ssis-delay-validation/](https://www.dbafire.com/2015/10/07/ssis-delay-validation/)

Comment: As soon as i parameterize the connection string a red cross mark is appearing on the data flow task. When tried to execute the task facing the following error.

Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  
     The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Source_Connection" failed with error code 0xC0202009. 

Tried with delay validation of the dataflowtask set to true, but still facing the issue.